# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' with streamlit

Tags: python, decode, encode, streamlit

I am trying to display a pipeline script on the UI with streamlit and facing this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

My code is as follow

```
data_file = st.file_uploader("Upload raw file", type=["docx"])

    with open(os.path.join("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw", data_file.name),
              "wb") as f:
        f.write(data_file.getbuffer())
```

The error i am getting:
[image: error on the UI]

If you guys know how to avoid this small error showing on the UI, please do share here, it would help alot:)

Answer (score 1):

Put **data_file** to a condition of **if statement**

```py
data_file = st.file_uploader("Upload raw file", type=["docx"])

if data_file is not None: # Added missing if statement
    with open(os.path.join("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw", data_file.name),
              "wb") as f:
        f.write(data_file.getbuffer())
```